# Macro for reference to a figure with a page number

Tags: cross-referencing

I have

```
Figure \ref{sp}
```

which gives

```
Figure 3
```

I want to get

```
Figure 3, p. 13
```

**Is there any macro for a reference of figure and page number?**

Comment: `Figure~\ref{sp}, p.~\pageref{sp}`

Comment: Do you do a search on the site before asking a question? The search `page reference figure` would have led you directly to the answer...

Comment: @Jubobs But this question has produced a cleverer answer. Any chance to merge these two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also use the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package to avoid writing each time "figure" or "p.".

So writing

```
\Cref{sp}, \cpageref{sp}
```

gives what you want if you define the following formats

```
\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}

\begin{document}
Some text
\newpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{text}\label{sp}
\end{figure}

\Cref{sp}, \cpageref{sp}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

You can even create your own commands to automate this:

```
\newcommand{\Crefplus}[1]{\Cref{#1}, \cpageref{#1}}
\newcommand{\crefplus}[1]{\cref{#1}, \cpageref{#1}}
```

and use them as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefname{page}{p.}{pp.}
\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}

\newcommand{\Crefplus}[1]{\Cref{#1}, \cpageref{#1}}
\newcommand{\crefplus}[1]{\cref{#1}, \cpageref{#1}}

\begin{document}
Some text
\newpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{text}\label{sp}
\end{figure}

\Crefplus{sp} at the beginning of line.

Inside a line \crefplus{sp}.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: similar you can obtain with package varioref

Comment: Is there any macro for this?

Comment: @Masi Answer edited.

Comment: Similarly, you can use fancyref to do this.